# laravel-notification-channels/apn either isn't sending notification or my iPhone isn't receiving the notification

Tags: php, ios, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I am [using this package](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/apn) to try and send apn notifications in my Laravel app. However, I have followed the documentation on the main page, and when I try to send an apn notification, I can log on the server that the constructor and via methods are called, but I can't figure out why my notification either isn't being sent or isn't being received. My logs have no info from the package either.

How do I troubleshoot this? What am I missing?

MyNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use NotificationChannels\Apn\ApnChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Apn\ApnMessage;

class MyNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        Log::debug('MyNotification constructor called');
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        Log::debug('MyNotification via called');
        return [ApnChannel::class];
    }

    public function toApn($notifiable)
    {
        Log::debug('MyNotification toApn called');
        return ApnMessage::create()
            ->badge(1)
            ->title('My title')
            ->body('My body');
    }

    public function routeNotificationForApn($notifiable)
    {
        Log::debug('MyNotification routeNotificationForApn called');
        return $notifiable->token;
    }
}
```

usage code in MyController.php

```
    public function sendNotification(MyModel $model)
    {
    // authorization checks here...

        $devices = Device::where('user_id', $model->user_id)->get();
        Notification::send($devices, new MyNotification());

        return response()->json(null, 200);
    }
```

Here is what my broadcasting.php and .env files look like:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the function `routeNotificationForApn()` belongs in the notifiable *model* (in my instance, `Device`), not in the `MyNotification` class.

Removing the `use Queueable;` is required as well if you don't have a queue set up.

Answer (score 0):

Your notification uses `Queueable` so your notifications are only send if your [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#queueing-notifications) is correctly setup.

You can run your queue locally by running

```sh
$ php artisan queue:work
```

On your console you would also get a feedback if your queued job (your notification) has been submitted successfully (not if it is delivered successfully).

This is also highlighted inside the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#queueing-notifications)

> Before queueing notifications you should configure your queue and start a worker.

If you need a queue that is probably sth. you need to decide as only you know how much load is the application, how many notifications should be sent.

Taken from the docs:

> Sending notifications can take time, especially if the channel needs to make an external API call to deliver the notification. To speed up your application's response time, let your notification be queued by adding the ShouldQueue interface and Queueable trait to your class.

Personal opinion: Make it work without a queue, f. ex. locally, and then add a queue.

If you configured to run your queue with Redis, I would highly recommend to use [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon) to monitor the jobs in your queue.

#### Tips for using APN

Configure the APN service correctly in `config/broadcasting.php` - see [Github docs](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/apn#setting-up-the-apn-service).

Comment: Can I remove the ```use Queueable``` to avoid setting up a queue, or is that bad practice?

Comment: When I run php artisan queue:work or php artisan queue:listen it just seems to hang, and I have to ctrl-C to get back to a prompt. Removing use Queueable doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you make sure that you configured the APN service correctly? I updated my answer accordingly. Maybe you can show us whats inside your `config/broadcasting.php` file.

Comment: Did you also check Laravels error log? It is most likely at `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I did check the logs, no luck. I'm going to take another look at my broadcasting.php config.

Comment: I have updated my question with the relevant sections from broadcasting.php and .env